# Nullable object must have a value. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need help. I'm having problem in my program. This is my code on my Business logic layer.

```
Function Load_ItemDetails(ByVal ItemID As String) As Items
    Dim objItemEnt As New tblitem
    Dim objitem As New Items
    Try
        Using da = New DataAccess
            objItemEnt = da.Load_ItemDetails(ItemID)
            With objitem
                .ItemCode = objItemEnt.ItemCode
                .ItemName = objItemEnt.ItemName
                .Description = objItemEnt.Description
                .NameofType = objItemEnt.NameofType
                .TypeofPricing = objItemEnt.TypeofPricing
                .OnStock = objItemEnt.OnStock
                .ItemPrice = objItemEnt.ItemPrice
                .DateModified = objItemEnt.DateModified
            End With
            Return objitem
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Function
```

This code is for my data access layer.

```
Public Function Load_ItemDetails(ByVal ItemCode As String)
    Dim objitem As New tblitem
    Try
        Using entItem = New DAL.systemdbEntities1
            Dim qryUsers = From p In entItem.tblitems
           Where p.ItemCode = ItemCode
           Select p

            Dim luser As List(Of tblitem) = qryUsers.ToList
            If luser.Count > 0 Then
                Return luser.First
            Else
                Return objitem
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Function`
```

For my Presentation layer:

```
Private Sub Load_Item_Detail(ByVal ItemCode As String)
    objItem = New Items
    Using objLogic = New LogicalLayer
        objItem = objLogic.Load_ItemDetails(ItemCode)
        With objItem
            Me.ItemCodetxt.Text = .ItemCode
            Me.ItemNametxt.Text = .ItemName
            Me.ItemDesctxt.Text = .Description
            Me.ItemTypetxt.Text = .NameofType
            Me.ItemPricetxt.Text = .TypeofPricing
            Me.ItemOnstocktxt.Text = CStr(.OnStock)
            Me.ItemPricetxt.Text = CStr(.ItemPrice)
            Me.TextBox1.Text = CStr(.DateModified)
            Me.ItemCodetxt.Tag = .ItemCode
        End With
    End Using
End Sub`
```

and after I run, I get this error `Nullable object must have a value` help me. I'm stuck. I don't know what to do guys. I new in n tier architecture.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the architecture. And your code snipped does not provide enough data to help you solve your problem.

Comment: What object(s) are nullable?

Comment: this `.OnStock = objItemEnt.OnStock`

Comment: I would guess that `objItemEnt` is not being found and is therefore null

Comment: @eouw0o83hf, that would be a diff error - `object not set to instance`.

Comment: the `objItemTnt` is my table on my data set.

Comment: Did you debug to check variable for null?

Comment: yes. and it say in onSock.

Comment: `CStr(.OnStock)` is not the same as `.OnStock.Value`  you cant convert a Null to string

Comment: still i got the same error on my PL codes :(

Comment: is it on the `CStr(.OnStock)` line?

Comment: Ah @OneFineDay, proves my VB ignorance :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the value of a nullable object you use the `.Value` of the object. This nullable object also has a `.HasValue` boolean you can check before asking for the value. More here: [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

```
 If objItemEnt.OnStock.HasValue Then 
  .OnStock = objItemEnt.OnStock.Value
 End If
```

Comment: if it moves then it means this was the answer and you should check it as answered.  'moving' means you have more errors elsewhere